# Fullcalendar TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm getting an error and couldn't find any way to fix it:

> Fullcalendar TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

This my config:

```
config: {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    defaultView: 'agendaOneDay',
    defaultDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -14),
    minTime: '09:00',
    maxTime: '10:00',
    allDayDefault: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    height: 500,
    slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    firstDay: 1,
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    columnFormat: 'ddd, DD MMM',
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,

    eventRenderWait: 1000,
    events: [],

    resources: [],

    views: {
      agendaOneDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 1 },
        buttonText: '1 day',
        groupByResource: true,
      },
      agendaThreeDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 3 },
        buttonText: '3 days',
        groupByResource: true,
      },
    },

    header: false,

    eventClick: this.clickPlace,

    eventRender: this.renderPlace,
  },
```

If someone knows how to fix this please help.

And when I load developer page I getting this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
at CoordCache.getTopPosition (fullcalendar.js?228e:5594)
at ResourceTimeGrid.TimeGrid.computeTimeTop (fullcalendar.js?228e:11988)
at ResourceAgendaView.AgendaView.computeInitialDateScroll (fullcalendar.js?228e:11487)
at ResourceAgendaView.View.applyScroll (fullcalendar.js?228e:3863)
at ResourceAgendaView.ResourceViewMixin.applyScroll (scheduler.js?acd0:245)
at ResourceAgendaView.View.applyQueuedScroll (fullcalendar.js?228e:3851)
at ResourceAgendaView.View.popScroll (fullcalendar.js?228e:3846)
at ResourceAgendaView.View.onRenderQueueStop (fullcalendar.js?228e:3570)
at RenderQueue.intercept (fullcalendar.js?228e:1535)
at RenderQueue.dispatch (jquery.js?1157:5183)
```

Comment: Don't post error screenshots, please post the code.

Comment: @DennisVash done!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem of fullcalendar,  I use your setting and successfully to build the table. Can you post ur JS code?

Comment: @MatrixTai i'm getting events and resources from my API in Vue and set property for calendar events, all works on android devices, and windows, not working on mac and ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm find an error, I'm get the start and end time for config from `.toLocaleTimeString()` it returned the lines `09:00 AM` and`07:00 PM`, this is the wrong format for fullcalendar